# Access Application Bar of Application outside the scope of our applications in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, appbar

I am making a windows phone 8 App, and I access another external application outside my App. I want to access the Application Bar of this external Application, after it exits my App.
So my question is whenever I try to access the Application Bar buttons of this external App, I run into exception. I guess because it has come out of my Application, I am not able to access the App Bar of the new App opened.
Any way to access the App Bar of that external Application.

Comment: I dont think it is possible to access app bar of an external app from your app..and how are you trying to acess the app bar of external app?? Can you pls post your code?

Comment: Mind adding a code snippet? Though it seems that the requirement is impossible.